# Sql statement to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How can I convert this SQL statement into SQLAlchemy python. Couldnt find any solution yet

Thanks in advance

`select date_add(est_date, interval  -WEEKDAY(est_date) day) FirstDayOfWeek`

Tried this below query but didn't work
`func.dateadd(est_date, func.dayofweek(est_date), Interval()))`

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://"+user+":"+pwd+"@"+HOST+"/" + db + "?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes",
    echo=False, fast_executemany=True)
query_read = "select date_add(est_date, interval  -WEEKDAY(est_date) day) FirstDayOfWeek"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    dfData_old = pd.read_sql(query_read, conn)
```

Replace PWD, DB, and HOST with your values